# Tableau - how do we calculate ratio of one dimension member to others?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm looking to compute the ratio of one dimension member with others. My dataset looks something like this,

```
Name Role       City Country
ABC  Admin      XYZ  PQR
DEF  Marketing  ZZZ  YYY
GHI  Admin      PPP  RRR
```

Assuming I create a Parameter with the list of roles, If I select Marketing, I need show there are 2 Admin people for every Marketing person in the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to show the ratio of roles dynamically, as per user selection.  The data provided was very less, therefore, I have used the following sample data-

```
Name    Role
abc admin
def admin
gf  manager
asdf    manager
asdfg   manager
jhjh    assistant
ut  assistant
ii  assistant
eqw clerk
fvvf    clerk
egrthh  clerk
svfvf   clerk
etgw    MTS
```

Now proceed as follows-
**Step-1** right click `Role` field and create a parameter.   Based on all values it has, a parameter will be created automatically e.g. `Role Parameter`.

**Step-2** Create a calculated field `desired ratio` with the following calculation

```
{FIXED [Role]: COUNT([Name])}/
{MIN(IF 
[Role]=[Role Parameter]
then {FIXED [Role]: COUNT([Name])}
END)}
```

**Step-3** create one more calculation field (optional) with the following calculation

```
[Role]=[Role Parameter]
```

**Step-4: Build your View** drag `Sum(Desired Ratio)` to `columns shelf` and `text` marks card, `Role` to `rows shelf`, `optional field` to color marks card; you'll get a desired view like this-

[image]

Whenever you'll select a role from `role paramter` the view will update

[image]

**A little tweak in `text` and `tooltip` can give you a nice dashboard like this**

[image]

I think this should solve your problem.  Good luck

Comment: I am glad that it helped.  Please consider [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote#:~:text=Voting%20is%20so%20important%20that,that%20you%20have%20answered%20yourself.) though not mandatory

Comment: Hi, I did upvote but since I do not have enough score, I got a message mentioning that it won't be displayed publicly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, takes advantage of the fact that the type conversion function Int() converts True to 1 and false to 0

```
SUM(INT([Role]=“Admin”)) / SUM(INT([Role]=“Marketing”))
```

Alternatively, you could just make a table showing the Count of records for each role, and then use a quick table calc to compute percentages of the total.